# Export datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have trying to export `showing result` statement in below of `datatable` in Excel.

Here is my code:

```
table = $('#loadmaincat').DataTable({   
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "model/productListReport.php",
        "type" : "POST",
        "data" : {
            "list" : "list",
            "dataSrc": "data",
            "type" : "all"
        }
    },
    exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
            search: 'applied',
            order: 'applied',
        }
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question further more. Do you want specific column to be exported or full table or what ?

Comment: In jquery data table there is statement called showing result... I want to export this statement too.